# Align table inside table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have this table created:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Nom} & \textbf{Funció} & \textbf{Modes}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}& \begin{tabular}{c|c} 0 & 1 \end{tabular}\\
            \hline
            TRIS & Direcció & \begin{tabular}{c|c} Out & In \end{tabular}\\
            \hline
            PORT & Estat & \\
            \hline
            LAT & Escriptura & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
  
\end{document}
```

The problem is that inside the table the row 0 & 1 column delimiter doesn't align with the row Out & In column delimiter. How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: I think @cabohah's answer is the best solution, but in general if you want to align a `tabular` inside a cell you should put `@{}` at the beginning and end to eliminate the extra space that the tabular puts there. Like `\begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting one column, you can work with four columns and combine the two right columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}% Don't use latin1 for coding new documents. Use UTF8.

\begin{document}
%\maketitle% Does not work without \title{…}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Nom} & \textbf{Funció} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Modes}}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}& 0 & 1\\
            \hline
            TRIS & Direcció & Out & In \\
            \hline
            PORT & Estat & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
            \hline
            LAT & Escriptura & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
  
\end{document}
```

[image: unbalanced columns]

If the column with `Out` and `In` should have the same width, you could, e.g., use package `calc`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}% Don't use latin1 for coding new documents. Use UTF8.
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle% Does not work without \title{…}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Nom} & \textbf{Funció} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Modes}}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}& 0 & 1\\
            \hline
            TRIS & Direcció & Out & \makebox[\widthof{Out}][c]{In} \\
            \hline
            PORT & Estat & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
            \hline
            LAT & Escriptura & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
  
\end{document}
```

[image: balanced columns]